# How to perform web scraping dynamically using R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am trying to automate web scraping for different Physician Names. The process is I am having a list of Physician names in **.csv file**

1. The first process is,  the names of the Physician should be entered in the search bar of this [site](http://www.metacrawler.com/).
2. Then the search button is to be hit.
3. Then the first link is to be selected.
4. Then I want to perform web scraping to collect required details of the Physician.

These are the things to be performed.

The same thing is to be applied for every Physician.

Can anyone help me with this process using R?

Comment: Perhaps behave a bit more ethically. http://www.metacrawler.com/robots.txt forbids what you're doing

Comment: Is it not possible to perform in this site?

Comment: It not about whether or not scraping can be done, but whether or not you should be scraping when the site provider specifically forbids it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google searching 'web scraping with R' brought me [this tutorial](https://medium.com/towards-data-science/web-scraping-tutorial-in-r-5e71fd107f32) and [this tutorial](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/03/beginners-guide-on-web-scraping-in-r-using-rvest-with-hands-on-knowledge/). Both of these seem simple enough that you should be able to accomplish what you need. Also, heed hrbrmstr's warning, and see if you can acquire the data you need with abusing metacrawler's website.